# How to put the values in different columns into one column in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I have 140 column that for each row only one of them have a string value and the rest are blank. What I need is to create one column to have all the values and for all rows. here is the example:

Here is what I have

[image]

Here is what I need

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one has it we can use TEXTJOIN which can ignore empty cells:

```
=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,B2:E2)
```

[image]

Or without we can use INDEX/MATCH with wildcard:

```
=INDEX(B2:E2,MATCH("*",B2:E2,0))
```

[image]

Or even HLOOKUP:

```
=HLOOKUP("*",B2:E2,1,FALSE)
```

[image]

Or LOOKUP:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(B2:E2<>""),B2:E2)
```

[image]

Or XLOOKUP:

```
=XLOOKUP("*",B2:E2,B2:E2,"",2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Scott!!

Comment: Scott, this was an awesome response thank you very much! However seems like I do not have 2 of these functions available in my excel. I was able to do my job but I was wondering if you know why hat might be? TEXTJOIN and XLOOKUP my excel does not recognize them.

Comment: They are only available in Office 365.  Though TEXTJOIN is also available in Excel 2019.  If you have an older version these are not available to you.